# Present index.html no matter the location

Tags: node.js, express

I have a express app running on a node and would like the index.html to be presented to the client no matter the url location.

Example: `http://example.com`

should present the same page as: `http://example.com/test`

Current code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var path = require('path');
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

server.listen(port);

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to specify a route you can just use `app.use`:

```
app.use(function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.html");
});
```

Comment: This would only present it if the user specified /index.html in the url correct? I need index.html to be presented no matter the location in the url.

Comment: @GodsVictory I don't think so ... I think that this will always respond with `index.html` unless it's found in `public` first (because of `express.static`).  Give it a try.